# Why PayPal is not working in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I try to make a payment with using PayPal (payflow, payflow pro, etc.) but in result I get error:

> Your payment has been declined. Please try again

or

> The PayPal gateway rejected the request. User authentication failed

I have a configuration for PayPal in admin panel. What is the problem?

*Magento 2 (2.1.3, 2.1.4)*.

Comment: Is your Paypal account ready to accept payments?

Comment: @JonathanRibas I think yes.

Comment: Send your log to Paypal support, for me everything is ok on 2.1.4.

Comment: @JonathanRibas Thanks, this is debug.log?

Comment: Yes you will find Paypal log inside debug.log if you have activated debug on your Paypal configuration.

Comment: Please remove & add all credentials again. Make sure https is On for paypal